# Wordpress Menu: Condition on Parent Item

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a custom menu that is structured by a parent-child-subchild-and so on hierarchy. On each parent menu item (of which only six exist) there is a special picture I want to show in the corner of the website.
I now need a way to set a condition like this (this is fantasy-code of course):

`if (current_parent_menu_item == "Home") : echo "Picture01"; endif;`

`if (current_parent_menu_item == "About") : echo "Picture02"; endif;`

and so on...

I have no idea how I could access or ask for the current parent menu item.
Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot!
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a walker class for this kind of stuff. Here is a simple walker class that you can use

```
class MyWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function display_element ($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output)
    {
        // check, whether there are children for the given ID and append it to the element with a (new) ID
        $element->hasChildren = isset($children_elements[$element->ID]) && !empty($children_elements[$element->ID]);

        return parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        global $wp_query;

        // you know can access $item->hasChildren to do anything you want..
    }
}
```

If you just want to get over it, then you should use jquery to add the html to the parent element. You can do something like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(){
   jQuery('ul#id > li').prepend('<img src="#" alt="">');
}
```